# How to add tool tip on append tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I tried to add a tooltip for this `<a href="#">$0.05</a>` tag which is append through jQuery. Here is the full code:

```
$("#btnadd").click(function() {
             // Made it a local variable by using "var"
            var addkey = document.getElementById("txtaddkey").value;
            if(addkey!=""){
                $('<li><span>'+addkey+'</span><span class=\"amountin\"><a href=\"#\">$0.05</a> $ <input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"5\"/></span><span class=\'close ui-icon \'></span></li>')
                    .find('.close').click(function (){
                        $(this).parent().remove();  
                    })
                    .end().appendTo('#keyword');
                $('#txtaddkey').val('');
            }
        });
```

I tried with the code below but it is not working:

```
$("#keyword").delegate(".amountin a").tooltip({ 
            bodyHandler: function() { 
            alert('hid');
                return $($(this).attr("href")).html(); 
            }, 
            showURL: false 
        });
```

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Re-read your question - pretending you have no idea what you're trying to achieve - and decide if you think it's clear...

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is definitely not correct. You should call `.tooltip` in the click handler instead:

```
.find('.amountin a').tooltip({
    ...
});
```